# Nullable object must have a value. in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have following code in VB.NET:

```
Public Sub Test(ByRef clientId As Nullable(Of Integer))
    Dim t As Object = IIf(clientId.HasValue, clientId.Value, DBNull.Value)
End Sub
```

The calling side pass in `Nothing` as `clientId` value, but when I run this statement I got exception.

> Nullable object must have a value

Is my statement wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it to use "If":

```
Dim t As Object = If(clientId.HasValue, clientId.Value, DBNull.Value)
```

The problem with "IIf" is that it's just a function call - all arguments are always evaluated, while the VB 'If' operator behaves like the '?' operator in C#/Java - it only evaluates what it needs to evaluate.

Comment: Ouch, my mistake. I was thinking `null` and used `Iif` then I mixed `.HasValue` in it.

Answer (score -2):

```
 Dim cp As Single
        '    Try
If tt.getsumpaid4cors(CInt(sidtxt.Text), CInt(coidtxt.Text), CInt(tidtxt.Text), CInt(stidtxt.Text)).HasValue Then

            cp = tt.getsumpaid4cors(CInt(sidtxt.Text), CInt(coidtxt.Text), CInt(tidtxt.Text), CInt(stidtxt.Text)).Value
        Else
            cp = 0
End If
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.